# How to find lines with certain numbers

Tags: command-line

So I have this file that I want to find only the lines that contain a certain phrase followed by a nonzero number. I'm thinking using grep, but I'm not sure how to format it to ignore zeroes. A line would be like this:

```
2009-12-05 : Reindexing 100: [result]
2009-12-07 : Reindexing 0: [result]
```

And I only want the first line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To get the first match of the phrase `Reindexing` followed by a non-zero number, use (GNU grep):

```
grep -m1 'Reindexing [1-9]' < input
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean any "nonzero number", i.e. want to handle:

- negative numbers,
- fractions - including 0 < n < 1 (with leading '0')

you need something more powerful than grep. E.g.:

```
echo '2009-12-05 : Reindexing -0.7: [result]' | perl -ne 'print if /Reindexing -?(\d+(\.\d+)?+)(?!\w)/ and $1!=0'
```

This solution would also exclude strings like "100abc", which are not numbers: the "(?!\w)" part is negative lookahead meaning "not followed by word character". Altering the condition at the end you can make any filtering you like.